# Multiple adds deletes updates rows in one go Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, gridview, datatable

I have a grid view and a `datatable` is its `datasource` in C# Winforms application. Database is SQL Server and ORM is Entity Framework using database-first approach.

The application starts and database rows are loaded into `gridview`. Then user adds some new rows, deletes some rows and updates some rows. Then presses the save button to save it all.

As I don’t know how to save this specific scenario where some rows updating some deleting and some adding. So first I delete all rows previously reside in database and then insert all rows of `gridview`. Database is on WAN. So it takes a long time to save.

What could be the best approach to save grid view rows to database using Entity Framework when there are some rows which are added, some updated and some deleted.

**example:** 4 rows **A B C** and **D** loaded from the db to gridview. I update row **A** and **B** in grid view. Delete row **C** and **D** from grid view and add a new row **E** in grid view. and then I press save button So **A** and **B** should be updated in db and **C** and **D** should be removed from db and a new Row **E** should be inserted to db. that all I want in one go using Entity frame work.
  Please help!

```
public void SaveList(decimal ProjectCode,byte bomTypeCode)
        {

             List<BOM> LstBoms = GetModels().AsQueryable().Where(x=>x.ProjectCode==ProjectCode && x.BOMTypeCode==bomTypeCode).ToList<BOM>(); //.Products.where(x => x.StoreId == store.StoreId)
            if (LstBoms.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (BOM bomModel in LstBoms)
                {
                    interfaceObj.DeleteModel(bomModel.RowAuto);
                }

            }
            foreach (BOM bomModel in _gLstBomModel)
            {
                interfaceObj.InsertModel(bomModel);
            }
             interfaceObj.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't entity framework do all that for you? Bind the objects to the datagrid and then just update all the object? I thought that was a key purpose of EF.

Comment: https://techbrij.com/insert-update-delete-gridview-entity-framework

Comment: I read your article. that i know. i am not just updating gridview row. but also deleting the rows. and adding new rows.

Comment: example: 4 rows A B C and D loaded from the db to gridview. I update row A and B. delete row C and D and add a new row E. and when I press save button A and B will be updated and C and D will be removed and a new Row E inserted to db. that all I want in one go using Entity frame work.

Comment: In my opinion. I should have 3 lists. ListA will have info about updated rows. ListB will have info about deleted rows. ListD has info about new rows. and on save button every list know its duty and it will be done using entity frame work.